# Android : need to design exact like Super app?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have designed a layout as I have mentioned in this link [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/-QaJ6tEq3eM),

1st layout contains 3 icons which will work like an action icons and 2nd layout contains my CardStack.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="3"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list"
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:padding="12dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_connect"
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:padding="12dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chat"
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:padding="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

As I have given a link ,same I need to implement but i am not able to do, Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: I suggest you add a sketch of what you're trying to achieve, if possible.

Comment: I have given a link, in that link through video i have tried to represent my problem.

Comment: Tell me if I understood your problem : Do you want your 2nd Layout (FrameLayout with id=pager) to appear behind the 3 icons of your 1st Layout (LinearLayout) ?

Comment: Yes ..hichem..( Id=pager ) it should be hand o

Comment: Yes ..hichem..( Id=pager ) it should behind of my 3 icons layout... And pager would be below of my action button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your layouts in your xml file : put the **FrameLayout** (your 2nd layout of CardStack) first then your **LinearLayout** (the 1st layout with the 3 icons) like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_connect" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chat" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: Thanks bro... As you have done, I did that...actually problem was in different layout ...so I solved it...by the way...thanks for your reply.. :)

Comment: @AbdulRizwan I'm glad that you solved it. Good luck brother :)